# Network Time Synchronization with Java

Tags: java, networking, synchronization, streaming, timing

I'm creating a p2p audio-midi streaming application using Java (unfortunately)
and I'm searching for a way to provide network time synchronization
between certain peers (sources) using a reliable protocol implementation (like NTP)
but I can't find any related libraries to use.I also have a limited amount of time to
spend in order to implement something like this myself. So, does anyone know any solutions
for network time synchronization using Java, NTP or alternative protocols/methods/ideas ?
I will really appreciate any ideas! Thank you!

Comment: why unfortunately java?.. could be worse, could be in something like PHP :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jakarta Commons](http://commons.apache.org/net/) has an [NTP component](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ntp/package-summary.html) together with [examples](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/examples/ntp/package-summary.html).