# Time synchronization between server and Internet using Java

Tags: java, time

I have an assignment for developing a messenger for 1 server and 3 clients. I am facing a problem with time synchronization: I have to synchronize the server time with the internet and then synchronize the clients also. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Time Synchronization should be a something the OS should be doing. But since this is homework, I would suggest you use an NTP library.

Answer (score 7):

Use [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to synchronize the different clocks. You'll want an NTP library, perhaps [this one](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient).

#### See also

- [Java NTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925191/java-ntp-client)
- [Network Time Synchronization with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925524/network-time-synchronization-with-java)
- [Using Java to Query a Server for the Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193025/using-java-to-query-a-server-for-the-time)